# ¿Cómo imprimir un árbol binario de forma vertical?

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos

Necesito imprimir los nodos de un árbol binario de manera vertical. Tengo la siguiente función:

```
void Arbol::Alola(Nodo* a, int n){
    if(a != NULL){ // Si el árbol no está vacío
        Alola(a->Derecha, n+1);
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            cout << " ";
        cout << a->dato << endl;
        Alola(a->Izquierda, n+1);
    }
}
```

Lo cual haciendo pruebas con los números **50, 40, 70, 20, 45, 65, 90, 10, 30, 39, 49, 60, 69, 80, 100** me imprime lo siguiente en pantalla:

[image: Arbol binario]

¿Cómo puedo modificar la función para generar algo como esto?

[image: Arbol binario]

Comment: http://blog.martincruz.me/2012/11/arboles-binarios-de-busqueda-c.html

Comment: Segun lo que veo deseas que el arbol se muestre visualmente, podrias usar gotoxy y jugar con los los valores e imprimirlos segun la posicion que tengan en el arbol

Answer (score 1):

Prueba de la siguiente forma:

```
void Arbol::Alola(Nodo* a, int espacios=0) {
    if(a != NULL) {
        if(a->Izquierda) {
            Alola(a->Izquierda, espacios+4);
        }
        if(a->Derecha) {
            Alola(a->Derecha, espacios+4);
        }
        if (espacios) {
            std::cout << std::setw(espacios) << ' ';
        }
        cout<< a->dato << "\n ";
    }
}
```

Incluye la librería `iomanip` (para `setw`) y llama al método con `Alola(raiz)` y debería funcionar.

**EDIT1**
Lo único que se me ocurre es que recorras las filas por DFS y vayas imprimiendo.

```
#include <queue>
#include<iomanip>
#include<cmath>

int Arbol::tamanyo(Nodo *nodo) const {
    return (nodo == NULL)? 0 : tamanyo(nodo->Izquierda) + tamanyo(nodo->Derecha) + 1;
}
void Arbol:Alola(Nodo *root){
    std::queue<Nodo *> colaNodos;
    int totalNodos=tamanyo(root);
    int techo=log2(totalNodos+1);
    colaNodos.push(root);
    int pot=0;
    while(colaNodos.size() > 0){
      int niveles = colaNodos.size();
          while(niveles > 0){
            Nodo *nodoAux = colaNodos.front(); 
            colaNodos.pop();
            cout<<setw((niveles==pow(2,pot))?pow(2, (techo-pot)):pow(2, (techo-pot+1)));
            cout<<nodoAux->dato;
            if(nodoAux->Izquierda != NULL) colaNodos.push(nodoAux->Izquierda);
            if(nodoAux->Derecha != NULL) colaNodos.push(nodoAux->Derecha);
            niveles--;
          }
          pot++;
          cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias, pero la salida del código no tiene nada que ver con lo que quiero.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Mostrar arbol vertical]
Con el código que esta en el blog de Martin Cruz, hice una modificación en la función de mostrar implementando la función `gotoxy()`, la cual comparta a continuación.

```
int auxX = 0;//Variable publica.
auxX = 0;//se debe reestablecer a 0 cada vez que se desea llamar la función
mostrarArbol(miArbol,0);

void mostrarArbol(aNodo miArbol, int auxY){//auxY es el nivel del arbol


     if(miArbol == NULL){//Arbol vacio nada que mostrar

         return;
     }

     auxX += 5;//variable que permite posicionarse en el eje X

     mostrarArbol(miArbol -> izq,auxY+2);//Se para hasta el nodo mas a la izquierda del árbol construye primero el subarbol izq porque sus valores en X son menores

     gotoxy(10+auxX-auxY , 15+auxY);//posiciona el nodo segun sus variables en X y en Y

     cout << miArbol -> dato << endl << endl;//Muestra el dato del nodo respectivo


     mostrarArbol(miArbol -> der,auxY+2);//Se para hasta el nodo mas a la derecho del árbol
     //Se debe tener el cuenta el funcionamiento de la recursividad la cual implementa una pila para almacenar las instrucciones
}//
```

Comment: Gracias Johnny así es como quería que se viera el código y la explicación, es la primera vez que hago un aporte en este sitio, gracias nuevamente.